# Java read text and manipulate text data as integer

Tags: java, string, csv, integer, format

i'm trying to read a csv file like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
1, 1, 0, 0, 10, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
```

and convert into integer format and sum up for each row, but dunno why it's got error, my expected outcome should be like this:

```
[exam 1][LWD 5]
[exam 2][LWD 5]
[exam 3][LWD 12]
[exam 4][LWD 5]
[exam 5][LWD 1]
```

this is my java coding and i was using CSVReader library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //read text file
    CSVReader a = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    //store text data into arraylist
    List<String[]> aa = a.readAll();
    //create 2D array LWD
    int LWD[][] = new int[aa.size()][2];
    //store data to array LWD
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < aa.get(i).length; x++) {
            LWD[i][1] += Integer.parseInt(aa.get(i)[x].trim());
        }
        LWD[i][0] = i+1;
    }
    //display LWD
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print("[exam " + LWD[i][0] + "]");
    System.out.print("[LWD " + LWD[i][1] + "]");
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

this is the error result i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: In csv format you don't have whitespaces. What error/result did you get?

Comment: To confirm, which line of code is line 20?

Comment: this is line 20:
LWD[i][1] += Integer.parseInt(aa.get(i)[x].trim());

Comment: +1 it just helped me to practice more lambda expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that CSVReader is giving an empty string at the end of each line because of the trailing commas.

For example, when I run your exact code, but remove the trailing commas from the csv file like this:

0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
1, 1, 0, 0, 10, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0

It gives the proper output.

I suppose you could either account for this by skipping the last String in each of the String arrays or changing the csv file(s)

**Edit:**
Here's a quick fix that should work with the current csv format:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //read text file
    CSVReader a = new CSVReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    //store text data into arraylist
    List<String[]> aa = a.readAll();
    //create 2D array LWD
    int LWD[][] = new int[aa.size()][2];
    //store data to array LWD
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < aa.get(i).length-1; x++) {
            LWD[i][1] += Integer.parseInt(aa.get(i)[x].trim());
        }
        LWD[i][0] = i+1;
    }
    //display LWD
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("[exam " + LWD[i][0] + "]");
        System.out.print("[LWD " + LWD[i][1] + "]");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

All I changed was line 10, for `(int x = 0; x < aa.get(i).length-1; x++)`
Changed `x < aa.get(i).length` to `x < aa.get(i).length - 1` 
It might be more elegant to check if the string is empty instead, you might want to do that depending on the rest of the `csv` files.

Answer (score 2):

Each line ends with ",". The `CSVReader` thinks there is an empty character at the end. 
When you are calling this

```
Integer.parseInt(aa.get(i)[x].trim())
```

the `aa.get(i)[x].trim()` returns "" for each row when it gets to the end of the row.

Answer (score 1):

**I know you wanted to figure your issue out, and you have already had your answer.**

I just post this way up to give you more variety which has less headache. I solved wit lambda expression

Code:

```
String[][] numbers = {{"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0"},
    {"0", "1", "2", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0"},
    {"1", "1", "0", "0", "10", "0"},
    {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0"},
    {"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"}};

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
            l.add(numbers[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.print("[exam " + (i + 1) + "]");
        System.out.print("[LWD " + l.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).reduce((a, b) -> a + b).get() + "]\n");
        l.clear();

    }
```

Output:

```
[exam 1][LWD 5]
[exam 2][LWD 5]
[exam 3][LWD 12]
[exam 4][LWD 5]
[exam 5][LWD 1]
```